# How to replace a string and number with the same string and random number using sed/awk?

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed, awk

I have a text file that has, amongst other data, many occurrences of a string with a random number (between 0-n) appended. For example:

```
string1
string33
string10
```

and so on.

I want to be able to replace each of those with the same string but with a random number (between 0-n) appended. For example:

```
string2
string9
string12
```

I've tried this nawk script but I can only get it to replace all numbers in the file.

```
nawk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="";srand()}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)sub(/[0-9]/,("string")int(10*rand()),$i)}1' infile > outfile
```

Plus, it replaces each number, so a double-digit number could end up being three or four. For example:

```
stringstring4
stringstring30
stringstring3string6
```

Can anyone help me get the desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
$ nawk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="";srand()}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)sub(/[0-9]/,int(10*rand()),$i)}1' infile
string5
string89
string57

$ nawk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="";srand()}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)sub(/[0-9]/,int(10*rand()),$i)}1' file
string6
string08
string37
```

Note I just replaced this:

```
sub(/[0-9]/,("string")int(10*rand()),$i)
            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

with:

```
sub(/[0-9]/,int(10*rand()),$i)
```

---

### Update

> I think I wasn't clear in my question. I want it to only replace
>   instances of "string + number" not all numbers in the file as there is
>   other data within the file

Keep it simple, no need to set FS:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(/string[0-9]*/,"string"int(10*rand()),$i)}1' file
```

Look for `"string"` plus many `[0-9]` and then replace with `"string"` plus `random`.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
string1
string33
string10
hello2
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(/string[0-9]*/,"string"int(10*rand()),$i)}1' a
string1
string7
string4
hello2
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(/string[0-9]*/,"string"int(10*rand()),$i)}1' a
string9
string3
string5
hello2
```

Comment: I think I wasn't clear in my question. I want it to only replace instances of "string + number" not all numbers in the file as there is other data within the file

Comment: @hellocatfood uhms, the input data made me think it was just "string". check my updated answer, I did some changes to former code.

Comment: Interestingly, it only randomises the numbers once, no matter how many times I run the script on the file.

Comment: @hellocatfood I added a `*` into the condition, so it catches all numbers after "string". In my case it is showing different numbers every time.